# Field userDao in com.curso.controllers.UserControllers required a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea

Doing a course I found that at the time of performing the dependency injection following the instructions I encountered the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtof1.png)

I leave you the classes I have used:

## UserControllers.java:

```
package com.cursito.curso.controllers;

import com.cursito.curso.dao.UserDao;
import com.cursito.curso.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@RestController
public class UserControllers {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "userss")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userDao.getUsers();
    }

}

# 

# UserDao.java:

package com.cursito.curso.dao;

import com.cursito.curso.models.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao  {
List\<User\> getUsers();
}
```

## UserDaoImplementation.java:

```
import com.cursito.curso.models.User;
import jakarta.persistence.\*;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImplementation implements UserDao {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        String query = "FROM User";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    
    }

}
```

## User.java:

```
package com.cursito.curso.models;

import jakarta.persistence.\*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "telefono")
    private String telefono;
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

}
```

## CursoApplication.java (Main):

```
package com.cursito.curso;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CursoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CursoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## Application.properties:

```
\#GENERAL
server.port=8081

\#DATABASE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/cursospring?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

## pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

\<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
\<modelVersion\>4.0.0\</modelVersion\>
\<parent\>
\<groupId\>org.springframework.boot\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>spring-boot-starter-parent\</artifactId\>
\<version\>3.1.2\</version\>
\<relativePath/\> \<!-- lookup parent from repository --\>
\</parent\>
\<groupId\>com.cursito\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>curso\</artifactId\>
\<version\>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\</version\>
\<packaging\>war\</packaging\>
\<name\>curso\</name\>
\<description\>Demo project for Spring Boot\</description\>
\<properties\>
\<java.version\>11\</java.version\>
\</properties\>
\<dependencies\>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have tried everything I have searched the internet , even instantiating objects of the EntityManagerFactory class in a thousand ways but I can not get it to work.Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: What do you think `exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}` does? Do you think JPA will work without a datasource connection?

Comment: Thank you very much, in the course I was following the teacher added because it gave him other errors and it worked perfect, once removed that I jumped an error related to the PublicKeyRetrieval but searching the internet has been easy to solve. Thank you very much for your help and your quick response.